# No puedo hacer push a github desde linux

Tags: git, github, ssh

Tengo configurado la autenticacion con ssh, y puedo clonar, hacer pull ver los branches pero cuando trato de hacer push simplemente no lo hace se queda parado con el mensaje

```
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 129.56 KiB | 1.38 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Y asi puede pasar horas de horas que nunca lo termina de hacer push

Comment: puedes obtener el origin a ver que sale?

Comment: me permite hacer todas las operaciones de clone, pull, pero cuando trato de hacer push se queda parado y no lo completa

Comment: Juega con `GIT_TRACE` a ver si te sale algo interesante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems

Comment: no pregunte si te permitia todas las operaciones, te estoy pidiendo que obtengas el origin y agregues le resultado a la pregunta para verificar que no estes con un deatached head